# Import XML files in a view in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I need some suggestions on the topic- import xml files in a view under a schema and the files will be imported in collection into Marklogic.
For csv files/ excel files we can use the template driven extraction method.

As XML files have a hierarchy of elements, so is that possible to create a structure of that xml file in a template and load the actual file with mlcp import?

Example of the XML file :

```
<ns9:DocumentHeader>
        <ns9:DocRef>1234</ns9:DocRef>
        <ns9:DocCreateDt>2021-02-21T18:51:43.2644278Z</ns9:DocCreateDt>
        <ns9:DocType>Shipment</ns9:DocType>
        <ns9:DocModified>Test</ns9:DocModified>
        <ns9:DocModifiedDt>2021-02-21T18:51:58.3422988Z</ns9:DocModifiedDt>
        <ns9:Version>
            <ns9:CurrentVersion>
                <ns9:User>System</ns9:User>
                <ns9:Timestamp>2021-07-20T16:12:00.3079321+01:00</ns9:Timestamp>
                <ns9:Comments />
                <ns9:VersionMajor>0</ns9:VersionMajor>
                <ns9:VersionMinor>0</ns9:VersionMinor>
                <ns9:DocStatus>
                    <ns9:StatusID>9900100</ns9:StatusID>
                    <ns9:StatusName>Updated</ns9:StatusName>
                </ns9:DocStatus>
                <ns9:Reason />
            </ns9:CurrentVersion>
</ns9:Version>
</ns9:DocumentHeader>
```

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to figure out how to produce views with nested structures, and whether to model different relational "tables" with rows to join?  That is definitely possible. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/creating-template-views#id_28999 If you have an idea of what you want those tables to look like, and are struggling to define the TDEs, provide some more details about the desired outcome and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: My requirement is to create multiple views and establish relationship with each other by primary and foreign keys. Is that feasible with Marklogic - please.
Also I have data in form of xml files which needs to be ingested in those views. Is that possible to ingest those data using mlcp ?

Comment: And views would look like this - 

```ViewName : PurchaseOrder - colums: PO Key, JobBookingNo
ViewName: JobBooking - columns:  JobBookingNo, JobType
```